# iOS 10 get Albums icon for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, xcode

Do you know if and how I can use the Albums icon found in Photos App for my own application? I want to keep the icons as provided by Apple. Just like you can create a UIBarButtonItem with the Camera icon or the Organize icon.

Basically, I want to have a UIBarButtonItem that looks like this

[image]

Comment: Why not take a screenshot of it beforehand?

Comment: Not sure I follow. I have updated the question to make it more clear on what I am looking for

Comment: You will need to create or source your own imagery. There isn't a "system" icon

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought but was hoping I was wrong

Comment: Try the icons8.com website

Comment: I'm saying: There it is. You _have_ the icon. Now use that.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote

Comment: the question is very simple: how do you use iOS's stock album icon in a toolbar. Not sure why one would down vote, other then thinking that using a screenshot of an icon is an acceptable solution.

Comment: Sure taking a screenshot is a solution just not the right one for me. What if the icon changes in the future? Do keep taking screenshots? I was hoping for a better solution.